# C segmentation fault printing buffer

Tags: c, file-io, buffer

This code compiles fine and runs perfectly until I try to print out the buffer. I found a lot of resources online, but I cannot resolve my problem! I would really appreciate another eye.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int store_file(char* file_dir, char* buffer)
{
    FILE* file;
    long lSize;
    size_t result;
    int i;
    char* tempBuffer;

    file = fopen(file_dir, "r");
    if (file==NULL)
    {
        fputs("File error.", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    tempBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (tempBuffer == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Memory error.", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }

    result = fread(tempBuffer, 1, lSize, file);
    if (result != lSize)
    {
        fputs("Reading error.", stderr);
        exit(3);
    }

    buffer = tempBuffer;
    free(tempBuffer);
    fclose(file);
    return sizeof(buffer);
}

void fsa_cycle(char* file_dir)
{
    char* buffer;
    int bufferSize = store_file(file_dir, buffer);
    char n;

    // This is the line that generates the issue.
    // I have also tried printf("%s",buffer); but that also doesn't work.
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\nSyntax: %s <file-name>\n\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fsa_cycle(argv[1]);
}
```

Any suggestion would be awesome! I know that the answer is silly. But it is difficult for me as a beginner to understand on my own. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Standard hints: enable all warnings & debugging information (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) in your compiler. Learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and the memory leakage detector (e.g. `valgrind`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Gosh you are right. enabling warnings is literally the first thing I forget when something goes wrong. Sorry about that

Comment: I think you should take the habits of always enabling all warnings. At the very least, if you are sure that some compiler warning is wrong, add a big fat comment explaining why....

Comment: Yes that does sound like a good habit. I'll get on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that `int store_file(char* file_dir, char* buffer)` doesn't change the original `buffer` pointer, only its copy. To change `buffer` you need to pass a pointer to it:

```
int store_file(char* file_dir, char** buffer)
// whenever referring to it, use *buffer instead of buffer
// e.g. *buffer = tempBuffer;
```

and call it like that:

```
int bufferSize = store_file(file_dir, &buffer);
```

Comment: Also, as @vidit mentioned (why did you delete the answer), you should free the buffer only after using it..

Comment: I thought it would automatically decay to a pointer? Must have missed that fundamental concept!

Comment: @MikeCorcoran but it is a char array?

Comment: @phileaton no it isn't, it's a pointer to some memory location that should have a 'char' in it.